# Mobile operating systems which can be targeted by Qt, QtQuick, QML and QtMobility

Tags: qt, mobile, sdk, qt-mobility, mobile-os

The number of mobile operating systems or platforms supporting QT based app development keeps growing. Not for all of them QT is the standard framework for building apps, therefore it seems the Qt support can be categorized as follows:

1. Qt and Qt based technologies (QML, QtQuick, QtMobility) are the recommended way for building mobile apps and part of the SDK.
2. Qt or a subset of Qt is supported as a secondary way of developing or porting apps, and there is support for a subset of QT APIs within the SDK.
3. Unofficial 3rd party or open source extensions enable development of Qt based apps for a platform.

Which mobile operating systems or SDKs do support development of apps using Qt in either of the above listed ways?

Comment: I'm going to add an answer with all the mobile operating systems and SDKs I'm aware of, feel free to add items to the list, or to correct my answer, since I'm not a Qt expert.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mobile operating systems with full Qt support in the SDK:

- Nokia Symbian OS: http://www.developer.nokia.com/Develop/Qt/. Since Nokia discontinued Symbian, Qt for Symbian is a [community effort now](http://qt-project.org/wiki/Support-for-Symbian).
- Nokia N9 / MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan: Full Qt support.
- [Mer](http://merproject.org/) (community Meego fork) and [Sailfish OS](https://sailfishos.org): Qt/QML are both supported.
- Canonical's [Ubuntu Phone](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/gomobile/) uses the [Ubuntu QML toolkit](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/programming-languages/qml/) and [Qt Creator](http://developer.ubuntu.com/get-started/qt-creator/) for native application development.

Mobile operating systems supporting a subset of the QT APIs:

- Blackberry 10 OS and SDK: The Blackberry 10 SDK contains the [Cascades UI framework](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qt_index.html), which is  built on top of a subset of Qt 4.8 and QtMobility modules. Apps can be created using [Qt, QtMobility and QML/QtQuick](http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/05/blackberry-10-cascades-available-now/). Another approach is porting an existing [Qt application](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/qt_index.html) that uses QtGui.

Digia, community driven (open source) and 3rd party extensions targeting mobile operating systems:

- Android: QT 5 port by Digia ([demoed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRQTzrsNeVk) at [Qt Developer Days Berlin in Nov 2012](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/20/qt-gearing-up-for-the-future/)), expected to be released by the end of 2013.
- iOS: QtQuick 1.0 port by Digia ([demoed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRQTzrsNeVk) by [Qt Developer Days Berlin in Nov 2012](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/20/qt-gearing-up-for-the-future/)), expected to be released by the end of 2013.
- WinRT / Windows 8: ([demoed](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jRQTzrsNeVk) by [Qt Developer Days Berlin in Nov 2012](https://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/20/qt-gearing-up-for-the-future/)) demo.
- Qt for Android port [Necessitas](http://necessitas.kde.org/): Has been [donated to the Qt project in Nov 2012](http://blog.qt.digia.com/blog/2012/11/08/necessitas-android-port-contributed-to-the-qt-project/).
- Qt SDK for iOS devices by [Mediator Software](http://mediator-software.com/): The product website does not contain  much information, but there are regular updates on [Twitter Qt4iOS](https://twitter.com/Qt4iOS) (links to apps in Appstore built using QT SDK for iOS are posted on Twitter).

Comment: The ports you mentioned (as demoed by Digia) are first party ones - or at least will be :)

Comment: The Android port of Qt 4.x called Necessitas - http://necessitas.kde.org/ - used to be a separate entity but was recently donated to the Qt project :)

Comment: Further, a version of Qt 4.x for iOS has been in the works for a while, and reportedly there are apps on the ios app store using it (though i don't know of any by name). https://twitter.com/Qt4iOS is their main contact.

Comment: Thanks, @leinir! I've updated my answer with the information from your comments.

Comment: Added Ubuntu Phone to the list of mobile operating systems with full Qt support. Canonical announced Ubuntu Phone in early 2013.